# Is it fine to use ECDSA with edwards25519?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

The [`elliptic.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elliptic) library allows instantiating ECDSA with the `edwards25519` curve.

I've rarely seen this combination in the wild. Is this fine? Are there any known bugs?

Comment: Are you sure? It does show `var EdDSA = require('elliptic').eddsa;` in the examples, so it clearly has an implementation of `EdDSA`. If it is possible then they may have forwarded it to that part of the library (that might require a code review though).

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't implement `ed25519`. I'm saying it also implements ECDSA over edwards25519: `var ec = new EC('ed25519');` will give you ECDSA over `edwards25519`.

Comment: I believe you, I'm just wondering what happens below the API level. If you look [here](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic/blob/master/lib/elliptic/curves.js) you can see the definition of all the curves including edwards curves, and if you look [here](https://github.com/indutny/elliptic/tree/master/lib/elliptic/curve) you can find the calculations performed for each curve.